# Xcode App Release with Team Name as Category

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

So when i'm trying to deploy an App to my iphone using "Run" or even when i deploy it through "Archive" with "AD-HOC" mode, the app is appearing within apps library with the team name and not with the category assign to it in "LSApplicationCategoryType" on "info.plist" file, which is "public.app-category.utilities".
Is there any way to solve this?

Follow is the Apps Library that i'm talking about:

[image: Apps Library]

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the apple support itself I got:

“The behavior you're describing is expected. The Apps Library uses the categorization that is selected in App Store Connect, and visible in the App Store, to help categorize apps on the device.

As you are deploying an app directly to the device, and not via the App Store, it uses your Team name.

Also note the LSApplicationCategoryType is not relevant here. It's a macOS key. Setting it on an iOS apps will not have any impact.”

So there is no way to change this behavior unless the team name is changed or a new one is created with another name.